# Android - Firebase Quickstart Email/Password Auth demo doesn't work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

So, there are a couple similar questions on here, but none of them have a working solution for me.

I am using the Quickstart demo downloaded from Github. Downloaded today. I've changed nothing in the demo code.

Some common mistakes (from what I've read) that I've addressed:

- I have the project created in the Firebase Console with the
  downloadable json file (created with package name). I have provided
  my SHA1 fingerprint.
- Email/Password sign-in method is checked.
- I have Google Play Services and Google Repository updated and installed (from the Android
  Studio SDK manager)
- On my device Google Play Services is version 9.4.52

If I turn on the Anonymous sign-in option in the Firebase Console, I'm able to successfully Anonymously sign in on the demo app. But Email/Password will not work.

Edit: Not sure if I'm doing this right, but I got these in Logcat

```
D/EmailPassword: createAccount:chris884@gmail.com
 W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
 W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
 W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
 D/EmailPassword: createUserWithEmail:onComplete:false
```

Comment: Post the `logcat` produced by [this Log statement](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/EmailPasswordActivity.java#L160) in the Quickstart code.

Comment: Provide Error logs and code snippet so we can help you further.  In the meantime,  you may check what would be the cause by adding this code in onComplete callback task.getException().getMessage

Comment: @qbix Alright, check my edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `logcat` output shows that the creation of the user account is failing.  The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) indicates this can happen for these reasons:

- the password is not strong enough (less than 6 characters)
- the email address is malformed
- there already exists an account with the given email address

Add a `Log` statement to the completion listener for `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` to see what the failure reason is:

```
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
    Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Failed=" + task.getException().getMessage()); //ADD THIS

        Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, R.string.auth_failed,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    hideProgressDialog();
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
}
```

Comment: The password strength requirement is not prominently documented.  It's easy to miss.