# Task.isSuccessful() is false and unable to add any user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

```
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
EditText name, email, password;
Button submit;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.signup);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth    firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            // User is signed in
            Log.d("########", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
        } 
        else{
             // User is signed out
             Log.d("########", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
        }

     }
  };


 name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_name);
 email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_email);
 password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_password);
 submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
 submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {

  mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(),  password.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(SignUp.this, new OnCompleteListener < AuthResult > () {
   @Override
   public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < AuthResult > task) {
       Log.d("###########", "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" +       task.isSuccessful());

 }
});
```

The `Task.isSuccessful()` always returns false and I am not able to add any user.

I have enabled email authentication on Firebase and am able to add users from the forge itself, i am left with no way to debug and figure out where the issue is.

All other settings like adding dependencies and copying the configuration file obtained from Firebase into the app directory have been done. Please help.

Comment: Did you check why the task always fails? Failing tasks have an exception that will be very helpful: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html#getException()

Comment: See this answer for example code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39427322/4815718

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! I was actually trying to push in mock data , and thus the email id i entered was not well formed...

Answer (score 2):

[image: User Creation. Showing the required length of password]

I encountered the same problem, and decided to create a user from the firebase console. Then the error displayed in the image came up. The password is required to be at least 6 characters long. When signing up a new user ensure that the length of password is at least six and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I attached addOnFailureListener() and it abused:

**The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section.**

```
private void register(final String user, String email,final  String password) {
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            FirebaseUser firebaseUserLcl = auth.getCurrentUser();
            String userIdLcl = firebaseUserLcl.getUid();
            l.a("userIdLcl="+userIdLcl);
            DatabaseReference referenceLcl = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userIdLcl);
            HashMap<String, String> mapLcl = new HashMap();
            mapLcl.put("id", userIdLcl);
            mapLcl.put("email", email);
            mapLcl.put("password", password);
            mapLcl.put("ImageURL", "default");
            referenceLcl.setValue(mapLcl).addOnCompleteListener(taskPrm -> {
                if (taskPrm.isSuccessful()) {
                    Intent intentLcl = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intentLcl.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intentLcl);
                    finish();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Signing failed,", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        } else {

           // l.a(task.getException().getCause());
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "You cannot register with this email or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener( e->
            l.a(e.getMessage())   //logging
    );
}
```