# firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) doesn't work for me

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make  registration to a App in Firebase, but it keeps on saying Unsuccessful.

Here is my code.

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText etEmail;
    private EditText etPassword;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
            //Start profile activity here.
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class));
        }


        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);


        etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

        Button btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

        assert btnRegister != null;
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        registerUser();

    }

    private void registerUser(){

        String email = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();




        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
            //Email is empty. Create a toast to enter a email.
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your email address.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // return to the email field.
            return;
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            //Password is empty. Create a toast to enter a password.
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your password.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // return to the password field.
            return;
        }


        progressDialog.setMessage("Registration on Process...");
        progressDialog.show();

        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            //User is successfully registered.
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration is successful.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            //Log in and User will start profile activity.
                            finish();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class));
                        }else{
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration failed. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

I tried Login Activity with an email, that I manually created in FirebaseAuth and it was successful. But the registration activity is regularly unsuccessful.
I couldn't find any error in the code. Can you help me please?

Comment: Just to clarify, have you enabled Email/Password authentication as a sign in method in Firebase console?

Comment: When the task is not successful, use `task.getException().getMessage()` to find out why.  See this answer for example code and a list failure reasons: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39427322/4815718