# Android Firebase Email and password authentication does not work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create accounts in an Android app using Firebase. When I add the following dependencies in the app build.grade file -

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.0.1' 
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.0'//added also tried 10.0.1
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I get the following cryptic build error (btw I'm not using any Twitter SDKs or anything to the best of my knowledge):

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.2.0
```

When I change the dependecies to:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'//changed
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'//changed
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

the app build and compiles fine, but when I try to create the account, I get the following error:

```
Projects created at console.firebase.google.com must use the new Firebase Authentication SDKs available from firebase.google.com/docs/auth/
```

I am at a loss as to what I should do because I think I'm using the latest version of the Firebase SDK.

Some more information is that I have used both `mFirebaseRef.createUser()` and `mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` with no success.

I used this [link](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#using-the-library-in-your-android-app) to change the dependencies.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing the [legacy SDK](https://www.firebase.com/docs/):

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
```

with the [new SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/):

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.0'
```

This will cause a number of problems and is the reason for this error message:

```
Projects created at console.firebase.google.com must use the new Firebase Authentication SDKs available from firebase.google.com/docs/auth/
```

For new development, you should use only the new SDK. Delete this line from your dependencies:

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
```

The latest versions of `FirebaseAuth` require additional repositories.  Make this change to your project (top-level) build.gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

The change is excerpted from the [Firebase Sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/build.gradle#L12-L18) project.  It will eliminate this error:

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.2.0
```

Comment: I have added the change you have suggested to my build.gradle file and the error has disappeared. I am also using these in my dependencies: compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.0.1' 
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.0'. Problem is that i still get the original error message "Projects created at console.firebase.google.com must use the new Firebase Authentication SDKs available from firebase.google.com/docs/auth/
". Any ideas?

Comment: I updated my answer.  You should migrate to the new SDK.  The [Upgrade Guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android) is helpful.

Comment: So... Sorry for the late reply. I followed the guide you provided and migrated to the new SDK. I find that createUser() cannot be used to createNewAccounts. One can only use mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mUserEmail,mPassword).addOnCompleteListener(... to create a new account. The problem is that i still cannot create an account even after doing all these changes. What could be wrong?

Comment: @moseskimani: You should use `task.getException().getMessage()` to see the failure reason. See this answer for example code http://stackoverflow.com/a/39427322/4815718

Comment: So. I finally got it to work. After following your instructions, i also cleared all data in the google play services settings. Thank you very much for you help

Answer (score 0):

you should use the correct firebase authentication version from Google:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
```

And you have to setup Firebase as it is described in the official [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Comment: Sorry. I should add that i tried to use both compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.0' and  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1' without any success. I used the table in the provided github link to downgrade the dependecies to the above set that compiled. Also the same up reads and writes data to the firebase database without any problem which tells me that firebase is set up correctly. The creation of accounts is the issue that i am faced with.