# Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.er

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I added the json file in app folder. Then added the gradle files for authentication and others in build.gradle.

First I initialized the FirebaseAuthentication Object

```
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

Then my Method for Signing up the user,

```
private void createUser() {
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mEmail,mPassword).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if (!isNetworkConnected()){
                    Toast.makeText(signup.this, "Check Your Internet Connection..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(signup.this, "Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(signup.this, "Something Went Wrong. Try Again Later ..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

As the condition I get "Something Went Wrong. Try Again Later" in Toast Message

And there is no error in logs.
Only the following firebase warnings..

```
01-15 20:11:54.042 22745-22778/com.buckydroid.chat W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

Comment: You should use task.getException().getMessage() to see the failure reason. See this answer for example code http://stackoverflow.com/a/39427322/4815718

Comment: Though we do trust on your question not being a duplicate, please edit your question so as to add a link to the related question you're referring to.

Comment: The problem was in password field.. I didnt know firebase had some prebuilt password conditions.. Thank you all for your attention :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a little bit of research I fixed the error.

I was entering password below 6 characters.. Thats why it was not registering me.

So after entering more than 6 characters in password field. Everything worked.