# Firebase not registering user

Tags: android, firebase, dependencies, google-play-services

ERROR:

```
    01-19 14:59:57.113 18766-18766/com.example.user.josephxerria100333 E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gms.chimera
01-19 14:59:57.123 18766-18766/com.example.user.josephxerria100333 E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gms.chimera
01-19 14:59:57.126 18766-18766/com.example.user.josephxerria100333 E/FirebaseCrash: Failed to initialize crash reporting: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zza: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Build gradle:Project:

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
        //firebase
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Build gradle:Module:

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.1'
    //firebase
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'

}
//firebase
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Activity:

```
progressDialog.setMessage("Registering User...");
    progressDialog.show();
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail,userPassword)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this,new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult>task){
                   if(task.isSuccessful()){
                       progressDialog.hide();
                       Toast.makeText(Login.this, "User Registered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
                    else{
                       Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Could not register user!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
                }
            });
```

The progress dialog just keeps looping and never stops. I have updated google play and google repository.Used Firebase Auth 9.2.0 still did not work! The fire-base json file is added into the app correctly!
Is there something that I'm missing?
Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: Can you post a more detailed log

Comment: Use` task.getException().getMessage()` to see the failure reason. See this answer for example code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39427322/4815718