# Android: createUserWithEmailAndPassword doesn't work (firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm learning to use Firebase and I started creating users and passwords that I can see in my Firebase console. However, the method createUserWithEmailAndPassword doesn't work and I don't know why, maybe a problem with the Gradle.
Here is the main code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
DialogProgress dialogProgress;
EditText editEmail;
EditText editPassword;
String email;
String password;
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editEmail);
    editPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    findViewById(R.id.registrazione).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            email = editEmail.getText().toString();
            password = editPassword.getText().toString();
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Email vuota",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Password vuota",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if(!(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)||TextUtils.isEmpty(password)))
            {
                dialogProgress = new DialogProgress();
                dialogProgress.show(getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(),"Dialog");
                firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
                    {
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registrazione avvenuta",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(dialogProgress);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registrazione fallita", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(dialogProgress);
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here is my gradle Project:

```
buildscript 
{
  repositories 
  {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies 
  {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
  }
}

allprojects 
{
  repositories 
  {
    jcenter()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) 
{
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is my gradle app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android 
{
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
  defaultConfig 
  {
    applicationId "com.example.utente.myfirebase"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
buildTypes 
{
  release 
  {
  minifyEnabled false
  proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-
  rules.pro'
  }
}
}

dependencies 
{
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: When you say the method isn't called, you mean it never reaches the onComplete callback? Or that the createUserWithEmailAndPassword is never reached.  You can check with your debugger by putting a breakpoint besides createUserWithEmailAndPassword and see if it stops there.

Comment: @snowman28924 the method is called but it doesn't work. task.isSuccessful() is always false

Comment: then call in else statement `task.getException()`

Comment: @Curio try adding this to your code within the onComplete callback

Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Failed=" + task.getException().getMessage()); 

This will let you know in your console why it is failing 

As explained here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39422364/android-firebase-quickstart-email-password-auth-demo-doesnt-work/39427322#39427322

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to log the result so you can know what is exactly the problem by using `Log.d("FirebaseAuth", "onComplete" + task.getException().getMessage());` it can be because you are not activating the email/password option in the authentication sign-in method or you password is less than 6 characters.

[image]

Comment: oh yes, the problem was the password!

Comment: That 6 characters info saved me.